# Counter++ and Counter-- example in android

Tags: android

I want to make an application in which i have 2 buttons and 1 edittext.The buttons are of + and - . When i click on + button i should get counter++ in the edittext and when i click on - button, counter-- happens and write it in edit text.
Now when i click on counter-- when the default number in edit text is 0 , it goes like -1, -2 ,-3 etc... But i dont want to take number less than 0 .Then what should be added to the following code.

Code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
     int counter=0;
     EditText et1;
     Button btnminus,btnplus;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_number);
         btnminus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
         btnplus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);

         btnminus.setOnClickListener(this);
         btnplus.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     public void onClick(View v)
     {
         if(v == btnminus)
         {
             counter--;
             et1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
         }

         if(v == btnplus)
         {
             counter++;
             et1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(v == btnminus && counter!=0)
     {
         counter--;
         et1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_number);
     btnminus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
     btnplus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);

     et1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
     btnminus.setOnClickListener(this);
     btnplus.setOnClickListener(this);
 }    

 public void onClick(View v)
 {
     if(v == btnminus)
     {
       int check=Integer.valueOf(et1.getText().toString);
       if(check!=0){            
         counter--;
         et1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
       }
     }

     if(v == btnplus)
     {
         counter++;
         et1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanx a lot!! its simple but i didntnoticed it thanx a ton!!

Comment: No problem, you can set first 0 text in onCreate() as i updated code. If this works, accept answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(v == btnminus && counter>0) // if counter at least ==1 it could be decremented
     et1.setText(String.valueOf(--counter)); //prefix decrement

else if(v == btnplus) // else if wont be checked if v == btnminus but counter is 0
     et1.setText(String.valueOf(++counter)); // prefix inscrement
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Comment: yeah, accepted answer has a "lot of expanations", sure.